# Xcode: setTitle not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, appkit

In my `AppDelegate` method `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

```
// Initialize here
NSLog(@"Application finished launching...");

MyMain* mainAccess;                    // To send messages to SAAMain
mainAccess = [[Main alloc] init];

NSLog(@"Setting title...");
version = @"v1.0";
[mainAccess setTitleVersion:version];   // Set Title with proper version
```

As you can see, I created an instance of my MyMain class in order to send a message to it (where all my important "main" methods are located). In this case, I'm trying to set the title.

My MyMain class has a method `setTitleVersion` and takes a `NSString` as a parameter (version).

```
NSLog(@"setTitleVersion called");

NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"Version: %@", version)];
//[_mainWindow setTitle:([NSString stringWithFormat:title])];
[_mainWindow setTitle:@"Test"];

NSString *mainWindowTitle = _mainWindow.title;
NSString *test2 = _mainWindow.value;
NSLog(@"_mainWindow.title: %@\n_mainWindow.value: %@", mainWindowTitle, test2);
```

I have an outlet of the main window attached to this MyMain class (as you can see with _mainWindow).

I added some `NSLogs` to try to debug myself. Both the value and title come back as `null`.

What am I doing wrong? The method is getting called as I can see in the console output. It's as if the `_mainWindow` outlet isn't working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your child has a bowl of ice cream, and wants a cherry on top.  You go to the freezer and get out the ice cream carton.  You get a bowl out of the cabinet.  You put some ice cream in the bowl.  Now you have a bowl of ice cream.  You get a cherry out of the refrigerator and put a cherry on it.  Then you throw the bowl of ice cream (with cherry on top) away.  Now you're confused, because your child's bowl of ice cream still has no cherry on top!  What did you do wrong?

This scenario is a metaphor for your problem.  You need to send the `setTitleVersion:` message to your **existing** instance of `MyMain`.  You can't just create an entirely new instance of `MyMain`, send the message to it, and then throw away that new instance.

Your comment on `rdelmar`'s answer says that your existing instance of `MyMain` is in your main nib, and you have an outlet to it.  I assume that means you have an outlet of type `MyMain` on your `MyAppDelegate`, and that the outlet is hooked up to a `MyMain` object in your nib.  In that case, you want to send the `setTitleVersion:` message to the object in the outlet.  If your outlet were named `mainObject`, you would do it like this:

```
[self.mainObject setTitleVersion:version];
```

If you haven't created an outlet in `MyAppDelegate` yet, you can create it and hook it up in one step using Xcode's assistant editor.  Open the assistant editor and make sure it is showing `MyAppDelegate.h`.  Then control-drag from the `MyMain` object in the nib into your `@interface MyAppDelegate`, like this:

[image: create and connect new outlet]

If you already have an outlet declared in your `MyAppDelegate`, you can connect it in the nib editor. Control-click on the `My App Delegate` placeholder in the nib's Objects list.  Then, in the outlets pop-up, drag from the outlet's circle to the `MyMain` object placeholder, like this:

[image: connect existing outlet]

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. I dragged an object from the objects panel into the main xib file and set it to custom class Main. How would I access this?

Comment: Naming a class `Main` is a bad idea, because that class should be implemented in a file named `Main.m`.  Because OS X uses a case-insensitive file system by default, that filename will collide with the file named `main.m` which is created automatically when you create your project.

Comment: Well I have a prefix added before Main which I didn't want to disclose. I'll edit it to MyMain.

Comment: Oh wow. So basically all I needed to do was provide the outlet for the mainObject instead of trying to instantiate a new MyMain. It works now -- thank you very much. I'm still trying to grasp my head around all the intricacies of OSX/iOS programming.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have an IBOutlet to connected to the Main class, but I'm a little confused as to what is what. First, you don't connect outlets to classes, you connect them to objects. It's hard to tell from your question, but I suspect the problem is that you're creating one instance of Main, mainAccess, in code, but that's not the instance that you have an outlet to in IB.

Comment: I have a Main object of type Main class. This Main object is in the main xib file where the main window is. The outlet uses the Main object.

Comment: Does your main xib file also have the App Delegate blue cube? If so, you should have the outlet in your app delegate, and use that outlet when you call setTitleVersion, not alloc init another MAin object.

Comment: Yes, I have the App Delegate within it. Wouldn't the same problem arise if I ever needed to send messages for different reasons then, too?

Comment: @Shane, I don't know what you mean. If you're sending messages to an object in IB, then you need to use the outlet to it any time you send a message.

Comment: I control-clicked (blue line appears) to drag the window to my MyMain class, in order to create an outlet. In the dialogue box that pops up, the object is Main. This object's owner is MyMain.